# select list disable option not working in firefox developer edition

Tags: html, firefox, browser

Select list disable option is not working in firefox developer edition. Here is sample 
[`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/CtqC6/) 
for select list disable option.I have check this fiddle in firefox standard edition and developer edition it is working in standard edition but not in developer edition.How to disable select list in firefox developer edition ?

Thanks